# How can I apply Flux all to a predicate that returns Mono<Boolean>?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor

I have a list of filters for my Spring Boot application that check whether my logged in user should be enabled or not, and the filters return `Mono<Boolean>`

Now what I want is to to pass my object to all of them, and chain the filters. But the point is, I need to stop filtering if any of the filters returns `false`

Here's my `Filter` interface

```
interface Filter {
    fun doFilter(obj: UserDetails): Mono<Boolean>
}
```

And here's my code for login method

```
private fun login(serverRequest: ServerRequest, securityFilters: List<SecurityFilter>): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return serverRequest
            .bodyToMono(LoginPayload::class.java)
            .flatMap {
                userDetailsService.findByUsername(it.username)
                        .filter { userDetails -> passwordEncoder.matches(it.password, userDetails.password) }
            }
            ./////////////////////////TODO///////////////////////
            .flatMap {
                val jwt = jwtService.generateJwtToken(it)

                ServerResponse
                        .ok()
                        .cookie(ResponseCookie.from("jwt-access-token", jwt).build())
                        .build()
            }
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build())
}
```

What I want is to filter my object by all the filters at `TODO` part, and 
do the final `flatMap` only if all the filters return true, and stop filtering and emit `empty` if one of the filters fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `filterWhen()` statement in combination with `all()`, for example (in Java code):

```
.filterWhen(userDetails -> Flux
    .fromIterable(securityFilters)
    .flatMap(securityFilter -> securityFilter.doFilter(userDetails))
    .all(result -> result))
```

I don't think there's an `all()` statement that accepts a `Mono<Boolean>` though, only a `Predicate<Boolean>`, so that means you have to write a "weird" statement at the end that does `result -> result`.